# TypeError: concatenate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'

Tags: python, numpy

I can clearly see an argument named `dtype` in [numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html).

What I can't do, is this:

```
np.concatenate((np.array([]),np.array([3,4])),dtype=np.int64)
```

Which gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 4, in concatenate
TypeError: concatenate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'
```

Without the `dtype` argument I get this array:

```
>>> np.concatenate((np.array([]),np.array([3,4])))
array([3., 4.])
```

But I don't want those to be decimal points (float) values.

Why can't I use the `dtype` argument?
How to make it **int** on concatenation even if my initial arrays had let's say **float** values?

Comment: `np.concatenate((np.array([],dtype=np.int64),np.array([3,4])))`  ?

Comment: or `np.concatenate((np.array([]),np.array([3,4]))).astype(np.int64)`

Comment: yes the second option answers one of my question. Thanks :). But still I wonder, why `dtype` appears in numpy documentation, but doesn't work with concatenate.

Comment: what is `np.__version__` ?

Comment: it is `New in version 1.20.0.`

Comment: @Epsi95 its 1.19.5 on my system

Comment: now you know the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html#numpy.concatenate) for `dtype` says:

> New in version 1.20.0.

Version `1.20.0` has only been [released in Jan 2021](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#history).

Check if you have the right version installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation of [version 1.19](https://numpy.org/doc/1.19/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html), `dtype` was not an argument of `concatenate`. So `dtype` was introduced in version 1.20.

Then you can update your numpy version. Otherwise, if your first array is of type `np.int64` and the second one contains only `int`, the resulting type is `np.int64`.

```py
np.concatenate((np.array([], dtype=np.int64), np.array([3, 4])))

array([3, 4])
```